# Set mime-type of a file for the browser

Tags: php, pdf, mime-types

I am creating a file using the function fopen and fwrite to write the content in it.

The data I am writing is binary (encrypted from a pdf file). Once the data is written, I check for the kind of the new file in my macbook and it says pdf, but when I run `mime_content_type` in my server, the output is `text/plain`.

The extension of the created file is pdf.

Code:

```
$fileurl = $targetFolder . '/' . $id . '.' . $filetype;        
$blockCipher = BlockCipher::factory('openssl', array('algo' => 'aes'));
$blockCipher->setKey('test');

$create_file = fopen('./public' . $fileurl, 'w');

$file_content = file_get_contents($files[$fileKey]['tmp_name']);
$encrypted_file = $blockCipher->encrypt($file_content);

if( fwrite($create_file, $encrypted_file) ) {
    chmod('./public' . $fileurl, 0644);   
}

fclose($create_file);
```

Any idea on how to set the mime_content_type to `application/pdf` ?

Thank you

Comment: you need to post your code, there could be something in there that's failing and/or missing.

Comment: have you tried `finfo_file()` as well? http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php the mime type is in FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.constants.php. you should also try on your server directly detecting the type in the command line. ie `# file something.pdf` btw. the extension does not (and should never) matter at all for mime type detection.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Code posted.

Answer (score 1):

Check the http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php function

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```

Comment: I am aware of the header function, I am asking if it is possible that when I use mime_content_type on the file, it says application/pdf instead of text/plain

Comment: If you correctly set the HTTP Headers like in this answer it should output the correct mime type. Are you setting it explicitly?